# How to replace a text string with this format in sublime text?

Tags: replace, sublimetext

I'm trying to replace a text string with the following format

```
> | Pr_p48_17_id: 2A2A4E4F56414C55452A2A2C | pr_p48_18_:
> 2A2A4E4F56414C55452A2A2C |
```

Using the sublime text how do I replace `| *****:` for one`,` (comma)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should start removing the `>` first and make a sole line

> `ctrl+A`, `ctrl+shift+L`, ←, →, →, ⌫, ⌫, ⌫, `space`

you should have your text like this

```
 | Pr_p48_17_id: 2A2A4E4F56414C55452A2A2C | pr_p48_18_: 2A2A4E4F56414C55452A2A2C
```

Make each number on a row

> `ctrl+alt+F`
>   search for `\|\spr`, enable Regex, disable case sensitive
>   put `\n\| pr` in replace field
>   press `Replace All`

You should end with this

```
 
| pr_p48_17_id: 2A2A4E4F56414C55452A2A2C 
| pr_p48_18_: 2A2A4E4F56414C55452A2A2C
```

Open again the search and replace bar

> `ctrl+alt+F`
>   search for `\|\spr.+:`, enable Regex, disable case sensitive
>   put `,` in replace field
>   press `Replace All`

You should end with this

```
 
, 2A2A4E4F56414C55452A2A2C 
, 2A2A4E4F56414C55452A2A2C
```

To make it a sole line again

> `ctrl+A`, `ctrl+shift+L`, ←, ⌫

Remove trailing and leading spaces and commas.